# Inno Setup abs(integer) function

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way of implementing an abs(integer) type function in Inno Setup?

I have searched the documentation and this function does not appear to be supported. I am also unable to find anything relating to this on the internet.

I need a way of returning a positive whole number when a negative is produced. I am using the publicly available code for replicating GetVolumeInformation (see below), with one modification to allow it to return the decimal value instead of the hex value. However, it appears that sometimes this will return a negative number, as I don't think Inno Setup recognises that DWORD should be an unsigned integer. So, for example, if VolumeSerialNumber is returned as -12345678, it drops the minus sign. I tried modifying the code with this:

```
var
  absVolumeSerialNumber: Integer;
```

and then adding:

```
absVolumeSerialNumber := abs(VolumeSerialNumber);
Result := IntToStr(absVolumeSerialNumber);
```

but this gives a type mismatch error as I don't think the abs(integer) function is supported. Can anyone help me with this?

```
//Public Domain code for GetVolumeInformation
function GetVolumeInformation(
  lpRootPathName: PChar;
  lpVolumeNameBuffer: PChar;
  nVolumeNameSize: DWORD;
  var lpVolumeSerialNumber: DWORD;
  var lpMaximumComponentLength: DWORD;
  var lpFileSystemFlags: DWORD;
  lpFileSystemNameBuffer: PChar;
  nFileSystemNameSize: DWORD
  ): BOOL;
  external 'GetVolumeInformationA@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function LoWord(dw: DWORD): WORD;
begin
  Result := WORD(dw);
end;

function HiWord(dw: DWORD): WORD;
begin
  Result := WORD((dw shr 16) and $FFFF);
end;

function WordToHex(w: WORD): String;
begin
  Result := Format('%.4x', [w]);
end;

function FindVolumeSerial(const Drive: String): String;
var
  FileSystemFlags: DWORD;
  VolumeSerialNumber: DWORD;
  MaximumComponentLength: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  // Note on passing PChars using RemObjects Pascal Script:
  // '' pass a nil PChar  
  // #0 pass an empty PChar    
  if GetVolumeInformation(
    PChar(Drive), 
    '', // nil
    0,
    VolumeSerialNumber,
    MaximumComponentLength,
    FileSystemFlags,
    '', // nil
    0)
  then
    //Result := WordToHex(HiWord(VolumeSerialNumber)) + WordToHex(LoWord(VolumeSerialNumber));
    Result := IntToStr(VolumeSerialNumber); //Change to Public Domain code to use decimal value needed by the installer rather than the hex value
end;
//End of Public Domain code for GetVolumeInformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Abs` function overload for the `Integer` type. The built-in `Abs` function has the following prototype and so it is not usable with integer types:

```
function Abs(E: Extended): Extended;
```

However, it is pretty easy to make your own one. Here is one way to write it:

```
[Code]
function Abs(Value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := Value;
  if Result < 0 then
    Result := -Result;
end;
```